# How to make a pickaxe that can break only certain blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can you make a pickaxe that can break only certain blocks in mcpe?

What is the command for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An item to break only SPECIFIED blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246297/an-item-to-break-only-specified-blocks)

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)